# Counting characters in a file

Tags: java, io

I am writing code that counts the number of characters, words and lines in a .txt file. My sample text file has 21 words, 2 lines, and 114 characters. My program output states there are 21 words, 2 lines and 113 characters. The file is mostly barren and is only meant for testing purposes. In the file is:

```
This is a test for counter function. Contents are subject to change.
This line tests if the line count is correct.
```

My program is:

```
public static void counter(){
    String file_name = "input.txt";
    File input_file = new File(file_name);
    Scanner in_file = null;

    int word_count = 0;
    int line_count = 0;
    int char_count = 0;
    String line;


    try{
        in_file = new Scanner(input_file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: This file doesn't exist");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try{
        while(in_file.hasNextLine()){
            line = in_file.nextLine();
            char_count = char_count + line.length();
            String[] word_list = line.split(" ");
            word_count = word_count + word_list.length;
            String[] line_list = line.split("[,\\n]");
            line_count = line_count + line_list.length;

        }
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: The file format is incorrect");
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: The file format is incorrect");
    }
    finally{
        System.out.print("Number of words: ");
        System.out.println(word_count);
        System.out.print("Number of lines: ");
        System.out.println(line_count);
        System.out.print("Number of characters: ");
        System.out.println(char_count);
        in_file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include the input, actual output and expected output as text (rather than the images).

Comment: @dave post has been edited let me know if the changes do not meet what you are requesting

Comment: tried something same, but its not recommended one. it creates unnecessary burden while parsing log files

Comment: The result of [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) does not include the line separator. This could be the reason your character count is under by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code for this would be

```
public void calculateFileCharecteristics(String fileName){
    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new 
    File(filename)))){
        String line;
        int lineCount = 0;
        int totalCharCount = 0;
        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            lineCount++; 
            int charCount = line.split("\n").length;
            totalCharCount +=charCount;
        }
    }
}
```